# Forward my .onion address to a different folder than my normal website

Tags: networking, server, apache2, tor

I want to create my own hidden service, and setted up everything correctly, I have my onion address, and I have a normal url for my website, I think it looks something like this:

*(www.xy.onion)* and *(www.xydz.com)* goes to *var/www/html/index.html*

but I want it to look like this:

*(www.xy.onion)* goes directly to *var/www/html/hiddenservice/hs.html*

*(www.xydz.com)* goes to *var/www/html/index.html*

Of course I could just buy another computer and set the other webpage up there, but is there a solution I can make this on a single one?

Answer (score 0):

I've found exactly what I was looking for in this tutorial:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/run-multiple-websites-single-ubuntu-server-using-apache2/